# django template loaders cached not load template from cache

Tags: django, django-templates

i am using Django 1.6 and i have this code in `settings.py`:

```
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    ('django.template.loaders.cached.Loader', (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
    )),
)
```

i think that the django loader cache is not working
i tried to make change in my template.html file and i could see the change immediately without any touch on the `app.wsgi`

what is wrong?

Comment: You have too many `(` in there. Is that exactly how it is in your settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, my mistake was that my django on production work with X wsgi processes, and when i did my changes on the html, my request route the a process that didnt fill the tamplate cache, then it loaded the template from disk.. after some requests all the processes filled the template cache, and than i could see that django uses the tamplate cache

Comment: Thank you!  I was trying to test that caching was working and this solved why I was seeing what I did.  I guess I assumed the separate threads shared a common cache of the templates.